# Is the name of winreg module name is different in pip install?

Tags: pip, winreg

How can i install winreg module?

When I try this

```
pip install winreg
```

It gives me this error:

```
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement winreg (from versions:)
  No matching distribution found for winreg
```

Is the name of winreg module name is different in pip install?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[winreg](https://docs.python.org/3/library/winreg.html) is a built-in module, no need to install it.