# PythonAnywhere ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'winreg'

Tags: django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-forms, pythonanywhere

we neither used this module called 'winreg' nor we touched anything.

Used this command **pip install winregistry** to install and resolve on pythonanywhere virtualenvironement

but we keep getting the following error.

Here's the error we are getting (attached) [image]

When we try to reinstall the module after getting this error - it shows requirement satisfied!
[image]

We also Referred to https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DebuggingImportError but did not help

Answer (score 0):

install this package

```
pip install winregistry

--------- OR -----------

pip install fake-winreg
```

if not get a solution then open link

[Is the name of winreg module name is different in pip install?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49497171/is-the-name-of-winreg-module-name-is-different-in-pip-install)

Comment: Only fake one is going to work on PythonAnywhere as it is Linux-based. You need to follow https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/InstallingNewModules to install it correctly/

Comment: Yes, you can install the library correctly using the commands provided in the PythonAnywhere instructions link that you mentioned.